# Adding a slider to html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a slider as in input on a web page I am designing. I don't even know if it is called a slider.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp

Comment: @Tik i need a double sided range, can you point me in that direction

Answer (score 1):

A "slider" is written like this but within <> tags:

```
<input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="0.01">
```

You can set step to 1 and set the minimum and maximum values however you want.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

If you're looking for two sliders, you can build it out of two sliders like this:

```
<input value="500" min="500" max="50000" step="500" type="range">
<input value="50000" min="500" max="50000" step="500" type="range">
```

> https://codepen.io/rendykstan/pen/VLqZGO

Comment: i need a two sided slider